# XSLT: Reuse a template within another template

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I have an XSLT file which displays the title and artist name of a CD. I have 3 templates, first template displays the title, second template displays the artist name, and third template contains a hidden table. The hidden table is displayed using a checkbox. I want to reuse the title and artist templates in order to show them as table data inside the third template when it is visible.

The problem is that the third template doesn't show on the browser because I don't know what to assign to the match attribute. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Expected Result:
[image]
![1]
index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
else 
  {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xml");
xsl = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog_apply.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
  {
  ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
  }
// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

cdcatalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

cdcatalog_apply.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css"> 

    .pdesc{
    display:none;
    }

    input[type=checkbox]:checked + .pdesc {
      display: block;
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

      <h1>CD Collection</h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog/cd">
      </xsl:apply-templates>

    </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="cd">
    <TR >
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
    </TR>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="title" name="title">
    <p>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="artist" name="artist">
    <p>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="X"><!-- I don't know what to put in the match -->
    <label >Show More</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ></input>

    <div class="pdesc">

    <h2>CD Details</h2>

    <table border="1" >
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
    <tr>
      <td> <xsl:call-template name="title"/></td>
      <td> <xsl:call-template name="artist"/></td>
    </tr>

    </tr>
    </table>

    </div>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is the expected result here?

Comment: hi michael.hor257k, I have updated my post with the expected result. So when the checkbox is checked, the table becomes visible.

Comment: Instead of showing the view of HTML in a browser, can you show us the expected output source code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two templates matching exactly the same element without some sort of condition, so you can't just match on "cd" in your third template.

What you could so though, is give your third template a "mode" attribute

```
<xsl:template match="cd" mode="hidden">
```

However, you would then need to have a second `xsl:apply-templates` where you specified the mode.

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog/cd" />
 <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog/cd" mode="hidden" />
```

Or perhaps you could call it in the template that matches "cd" currently:

```
<xsl:template match="cd">
    <TR>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="hidden" />
    </TR>
</xsl:template>
```

Note, in this "hidden" template, you don't really need to do `xsl:call-templates` as you are currently doing. You can just do `<xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>` again as you are in the first template.

Alternatively, you could remove the first template, and use an `xsl:for-each` instead of the first `<xsl:apply-templates select="cd">`. That would do away with the need for the "mode" attribute.

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <TR>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="."  />
      </TR>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Of course, do you really need two templates at all here? Couldn't you just combine them into one?

```
<xsl:template match="cd">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
    </p>
    <label>Show More</label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div class="pdesc">
        <h2>CD Details</h2>

        <table border="1" >
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Artist</th>
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:apply-templates select="title"/></td>
          <td><xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/></td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```